# Use ng-repeat and have one item of a list mandatory

Tags: html, angularjs

I'am learning AngularJs (v1.6) using Angular Material and I'am stuck on a small but annoying display problem.

I've created a simple list of items (fruits) with switches buttons. The user can switch on the button if the fruits is present. I used ng-repeat to display each elements of my list... 
Then, I tried to have got only one of my switches button mandatory, so I used the word "required"...like this:

The HTML:

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="(key, value) in $ctrl.vegetables.fruits">
  <p>{{'vegetables.fruits.' + key | translate}}</p>
  <md-switch class="md-primary" ng-model="$ctrl.vegetables.fruits[key]" required>
<br/>
  <div  class="warning" ng-show="key === 'banana'" >Ce champ est obligatoire</div>
  </md-switch>
</md-list-item>
```

But if I put it in the md-switch div, all the items of my list are required...
If I display the elements of my list one by one, I can required only one element.. but I would like to keep the ng-repeat.

So this is my question: How can I do to have only one of my item mandatory ?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to have at least one item in your list selected right? First of, vegetables are not fruits, but that's not the concern right now. You could probably check in your controller to see if one of the item has been checked. If you want to set only one of the item as required, you could use ng-required to set a condition on weather the field is required or not. I would need some info about the fruits to direct you further!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is as you want :

```
<md-list-item >
  <p ng-repeat-start="(key, value) in $ctrl.vegetables.fruits">{{'vegetables.fruits.' + key | translate}}</p>
  <md-switch ng-repeat-end class="md-primary" ng-model="$ctrl.vegetables.fruits[key]" required>
<br/>
  <div  class="warning" ng-show="key === 'banana'" >Ce champ est obligatoire</div>
  </md-switch>
</md-list-item>
```